# Unable to Connect to MSSQL Server from Apache Superset in Docker

Tags: sql-server, apache-superset

I am hosting Apache Superset and Microsoft SQL Server using Docker containers. While I am able to successfully connect to the MSSQL Server using Azure Data Studio, I encounter an error when trying to establish a connection from Apache Superset. The error message states:

```
ERROR: (builtins.NoneType) None
[SQL: (pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError) (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (@@172.17.0.2)\n')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)
```

I have checked the network accessibility and confirmed that there are no firewall rules or network restrictions blocking the connection. Both the Apache Superset and MSSQL Server containers are running without any issues.

What could be causing this error and how can I resolve it to establish a successful connection between Apache Superset and MSSQL Server in Docker?

What have I checked?

1. Verified Network Accessibility: I checked the network settings and made sure that there are no firewall rules or network restrictions blocking the connection between the Apache Superset server and the MSSQL Server. I confirmed that both containers are running without any issues.
2. Checked MSSQL Server Status: I ensured that the MSSQL Server container is up and running. I verified its IP address and confirmed that it matches the IP address used in the connection configuration.
3. Tested Connection Outside of Superset: I attempted to connect to the MSSQL Server using Azure Data Studio and confirmed that it was successful. This helped us determine that the issue is specific to the connection between Apache Superset and MSSQL Server.
4. Verified Connection Details: I double-checked the connection details, including the username, password, host (IP address), and database name configured in the Superset configuration. I made sure that these details match the settings of the MSSQL Server.
5. Modified Connection String: I experimented with different connection strings, including the use of different libraries such as `pymssql` and `pyodbc`. I tried variations in the connection string parameters, such as specifying encryption and trust server certificate options.
6. Checked Docker Network Configuration: I inspected the Docker network configuration and verified that both the Apache Superset and MSSQL Server containers are connected to the same network. I ensured that the containers can communicate with each other within the Docker network.
7. Tested Network Connectivity: I used standard network troubleshooting tools like `ping` and `telnet` to test the network connectivity between the Apache Superset server and the MSSQL Server. I verified that the MSSQL Server is reachable from the Superset server by checking the response from the `telnet` command on port 1433.

Despite attempting these troubleshooting steps, I have been unable to establish a successful connection between Apache Superset and MSSQL Server in Docker. The error message still exists.

Comment: So how are you trying to connect? If I run up a minimal docker-compose with `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest` and `apache/superset` with `pip install pymssql` then I have no problem adding a new database to Superset with the SQLAlchemy URL, `mssql+pymssql://sa:StrongPassw0rd@sql2019/model`. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76697219/edit) your question with a minimal reproducible example as there's not currently enough information to replicate your issue.

Comment: Your error message says "Adaptive Server". Are you certain you are using the SQL Server driver/library to connect?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that error can be thrown from FreeTDS as used by pymssql, often due to incompatible TDS versions, or even simply just by using the wrong port.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the similar problem, the following solution helped me:

1. Create a custom docker image:

```
FROM apache/superset:3.0.1
USER root
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.asc
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/11/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql18
RUN apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y
RUN pip install pyodbc
USER superset
```

2. Use the following schema to connect from docker image:

```
mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=servername;DATABASE=databasename;UID=username;PWD=password;TrustServerCertificate=yes
```

This solution worked for me for superset in kubernetes